# PouchDB Date/String conversion during Save/Load on iOS Safari

Tags: indexeddb, pouchdb, web-sql

Date on Safari for IOS get's converted to string during save/load

**Chrome for Mac**

1. Saving object with date field `(obj.date = new Date())` to PouchDB database
2. Read the same object - `typeof obj.date === object` (and it's a proper Date)

**Safari for iOS**

1. Saving object with date field `(obj.date = new Date())` to PouchDB database
2. Read the same object - `typeof obj.date === string`

So, in Chrome I get type persisted and on Safari not. Problem is when using this field in `<input type="date">` - Works on chrome but not on Safari.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/yoorek/v5fcw/

Is it normal? or a Bug? Should I manually convert string to Date (ugly and I think it;s PouchDB role)

Answer (score 1):

I responded on GitHub, but for the benefit of people on StackOverflow here's the link: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/2351

**Edit:** To clarify and not just link to the GitHub issue...

`PouchDB` is modeled after `CouchDB`, which expects JSON objects, not arbitrary JavaScript objects.

Out of all our backends (`IndexedDB`, `WebSQL`, `LevelDB`, and `CouchDB`), IndexedDB is actually the odd one out, because it's able to store more than just what you'd get with a `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myDoc))`.

However there is a real bug here in that IndexedDB is behaving differently from WebSQL, and I've opened a PR to fix that: https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/pull/2353.

Really IndexedDB should convert the Dates to strings before storing them, so you don't see inconsistent behavior across different backends.

Answer (score 0):

See [this issue](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/pull/2353) but the short answer is that `IndexedDB` (the backend in chrome) can handle date objects but `WebSQL` (used in safari) can not.